# RSolve: Recursive function is not a valid variable

Tags: difference-equations

```
RSolve[{
     g[n + 1] == g[n] + 10*(g[n]*Cos[-10 Degree] - y[n]*Sin[-10 Degree])/
          Sqrt[(g[n]*Cos[-10 Degree] - y[n]*Sin[-10 Degree])^2 + (g[n]*Sin[-10 Degree] + 
                y[n]*Cos[-10 Degree])^2], 
     y[n + 1] == y[n] + 10*(g[n]*Sin[-10 Degree] + y[n]*Cos[-10 Degree])/
          Sqrt[(g[n]*Cos[-10 Degree] - y[n]*Sin[-10 Degree])^2 + (g[n]*Sin[-10 Degree] + 
               y[n]*Cos[-10 Degree])^2],  
     g[0] == 100, 
     y[0] == 100}, {g[n], y[n]}, n]
```

When I run it I get the following error

> Solve::ivar: "g[n]+(10(Cos[10]\g[n]+Sin[10]\y[n]))/Sqrt[(-g[<<1>>] Sin[<<1>>]+Cos[<<1>>] y[<<1>>])^2+(Cos[<<1>>] g[<<1>>]+Sin[<<1>>] y[<<1>>])^2] is not a valid variable."

I believe that it might be an error with my syntax, but I have no idea what it is.

Comment: I can't reproduce your problems, but I do get the same input as output.

Comment: Are you using mathematica 10?

Comment: Yes, and I am running v.9 - same output

Comment: Can you add some initial conditions ?

Comment: To the code I added ", g[0] == 100, y[0] == 100" after the ^2].

"Equation or list of equations expected instead of True in the first \
argument {g[n]+(10\(Cos[10]\g[n]+Sin[10]\y[n]))/Sqrt[Plus[<<2>>]^2+\
Plus[<<2>>]^2]==g[n]+(10\(Cos[Times[<<2>>]]\g[n]+Sin[Times[<<2>>]]\y[\
n]))/Sqrt[Plus[<<2>>]^2+Plus[<<2>>]^2],y[n]+(10\(-g[n]\Sin[10]+Cos[10]\
\y[n]))/Sqrt[Plus[<<2>>]^2+Plus[<<2>>]^2]==y[n]+(10\(-g[n]\Sin[Times[<\
<2>>]]+Cos[Times[<<2>>]]\y[n]))/Sqrt[Plus[<<2>>]^2+Plus[<<2>>]^2],\
True,True}"


is the new error

Comment: Check `?g` and `?y`, maybe you have written `=` once instead of `==` or something.

Comment: I checked it, that does not seem to be the problem sadly

Comment: It appears the problem has something to do with there being two variables in one equation.
I am writing some test code to help diagnose the problem and I get the same error output when I have z[n + 1] == z[n] + y[n]

This problem only occurs when I add the y[n]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are not seeking an analytic solution you could numericize:

```
f[u_, v_] := With[{c = -10 Degree},
  N@{u + 10 (u Cos[c] - v Sin[c])/
       Sqrt[(u Cos[c] - v Sin[c])^2 + (u Sin[c] + v Cos[c])^2],
    v + 10 (u Sin[c] + v Cos[c])/
       Sqrt[(u Cos[c] - v Sin[c])^2 + (u Sin[c] + v Cos[c])^2]
    }]
s[n_, a_, b_] := Nest[f @@ # &, {a, b}, n]
```

Visualizing:

```
Manipulate[
 ListPlot[Table[s[j, p[[1]], p[[2]]], {j, 0, 20}], Frame -> True, 
  FrameLabel -> {"g(n)", "y(n)"}, 
  Epilog -> {Red, PointSize[0.02], Point[p]}], {{p, {100, 100}}, {1, 
   1}, {200, 200}, Appearance -> "Labeled"}]
```

[image]

Apologies for any transcription errors of your recursive relations.

Comment: I think this well help me quite a bit, I will go work on it for a bit and then let you know my result :3

Comment: @lyna You can upvote this answer if you find it helpful using the arrows and you can accept it if you think it answers your question.